# Is a countable union of intervals $[a,b], b \in \mathbb{N}$ equal to $[a,\infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Is the countable union $\bigcup\limits_{a<b\, \in \, \mathbb{N}} [a,b]$ equal to $[a, \infty)$?

I would say yes, because for every element $x \in [a, \infty)$ we can find a minimal $b \ge x$ such that $x \in [a,b]$. And every element of the left side lies in one of the intervals $[a,b] \subset [a, \infty)$.

But I'm not sure if this is indeed an acceptable proof or if I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and in general you should get used to returning to definitions whenever you feel unsure if something you've written is a proof or not.

For sets $R,S$, we say $R=S$ if the following hold:

- for all $x\in R$, $x\in S$
- for all $y\in S$, $y\in R$

Here the sets are $R=\bigcup_{b\in\Bbb N}[a,b]$ (for some $a$ presumable less than $b$) and $S=[a,\infty)$.

- suppose $x\in R$. Then by definition, there exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in[a,n]$, and since $[a,n]\subset[a,\infty)$, we see $x\in S$.
- now suppose $y\in S$, and let $m$ be any positive integer greater than $y$. Then $y\in[a,m]$, and since $[a,m]\subset R$, $y\in R$.

Of course, writing this so explicitly might be overkill, but if you are new to proof-writing, overkill is sort of the goal.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. Actually, it has a useless part. There is no need for you to take the minimal $b\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in[a,b]$. Just take *some* $b\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in[a,b]$. Such a $b$ exists by the Archimedian property.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks good.

$x \in [a,\infty)$ ;

Archimedean principle :

There is a $b\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $b >x$, then

$x\in [a,b]$.

b does not have to be minimal (your proof).

Your proof:

Consider the set

$B:=${$b| b \ge x$, $b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$}.

$B \not = \emptyset$ since by the Archimedean principle there is a $b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ with $b >x$.

Now pick any $b \in B$:

Then $x \in [a,b]$.